Informix PDO assoc_id error SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -25546
It has been about half a year that we have been facing an error on our production server. At the beginning it happened every 2-3 months, but last Friday it happened again and today once again. We have had an increase of users (maybe 100) in these 6 months. Users get error 500.
This is the error we get in error_log:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -25546 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]Invalid ASF assoc_id.

PDO_informix driver version:
Module release  1.3.2 

The only solution we have found is a reboot since restarting Apache doesn't help
Is there any command to check the so-called "ASF assoc_id" connections or maybe we are reaching a limit of connections?

I'm not finding much useful about this error, but see https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/listener-thread-err-25546

One version of the output from finderr -25546 says: -25546 Invalid network association control. — If this internal error recurs, note all circumstances and
contact IBM Informix Technical Support.  It shouldn't be happening, but it is.  Before contacting Tech Support, consider whether your Informix server is configured to handle enough concurrent connections.  Look at the NETTYPE configuration parameters in the $ONCONFIG file for the server.

One of my Informix servers has NETTYPE soctcp,1,50,NET for one of the NETTYPE entries (it is a test server that is never heavily stressed).  The 1 means "one thread monitoring connections", and the 50 means "it can monitor at most 50 connections at a time".  Increasing either number would allow more connections.

The link from @Barmar points to an explanation for XPS (IBM Informix Extended Parallel Server, version 8.x).  The mention of coservers is not relevant to IDS (IBM Informix Dynamic Server, versions 12.10 and 14.10 in support), but the overall suggestion — look at your network configuration — is valid, and in line with my prior suggestions.

@JonathanLeffler thanks! We have verified with other teams and a couple of them use the same database server with the same user, but they are not affected, so, NETTYPE  configuration doesn't seem to be the problem, am I right? Do you know if there's something else we can check?

I recommend contacting IBM Informix Technical Support given that the problem isn't obviously one of insufficient connections.  I am assuming you have a support contract, of course.
